# when are signals delivered?

Tags: signals

Do the sender of signals trigger a context switch to the receiver's process to handle the signal?

Or the receiver simply handles it when the process is scheduled to run?

Comment: What difference would it make? And if you signal several processes at the same time, then they will have to be done one (maximum n: where n is number of cores) at a time.

Comment: Sending a signal takes a system call, so it is entirely up to the kernel whether that ends the sending process timeslot, or returns straight back in. The receiving process gets scheduled when it is at the top of the priority list and a CPU is free (provided that the process has registered a handler for that signal, which could otherwise be ignored or fatal). It is up to the scheduler whether having one or more pending signals changes the priority.

Answer (score 0):

The signal is handled by (for) the receiving process when it is scheduled to run next time. It is up to the kernel's process scheduler to decide when that will be. To send a signal is a system call, that entails a context switch (to the kernel) off the sending process. The kernel might switch to the receiver, back to the sender, to some entirely unrelated process, or even go off doing some kernelly work.